# Ошибка серверного рэндеринга

Tags: reactjs, express, react-router

Использую связку React + Express + Webpack

**index.js**

```
require('babel-core/register');
global.__CLIENT__ = false;
global.__SERVER__ = true;
global.__DEV__ = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';

require('./src/server/index');
```

**server.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import express from 'express';
import compression from 'compression';
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server'
import { match, RouterContext } from 'react-router'
import routes from '../routes'

const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.set('views', './src/views');

app.use(compression());

if (__DEV__) {
  const webpack = require('webpack');
  const devMiddleware = require('webpack-dev-middleware');
  const hotMiddleware = require('webpack-hot-middleware');
  const webpackConfig = require('./../../webpack.config.js');

  const compiler = webpack(webpackConfig);

  app.use(devMiddleware(compiler, {
    publicPath: webpackConfig.output.publicPath,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    noInfo: true,
    stats: { colors: true },
  }));

  app.use(hotMiddleware(compiler));
}

app.get('*', handleRequest);

app.listen(3000, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    return console.error(err);
  }

  console.log('Listening at http://localhost:3000/');
});

function handleRequest(req, res) {
  // Note that req.url here should be the full URL path from
  // the original request, including the query string.
  match({ routes, location: req.url }, (error, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
    if (error) {
      res.status(500).send(error.message)
    } else if (redirectLocation) {
      res.redirect(302, redirectLocation.pathname + redirectLocation.search)
    } else if (renderProps) {
      // You can also check renderProps.components or renderProps.routes for
      // your "not found" component or route respectively, and send a 404 as
      // below, if you're using a catch-all route.
      // res.status(200).send(renderToString(<RouterContext {...renderProps} />))
      res.render('index', {
        title: 'Easy start with ReactJS',
        reactOutput: renderToString(<RouterContext {...renderProps} />)
      });
    } else {
      res.status(404).send('Not found')
    }
  });
}
```

**routes.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import Route from 'react-router/lib/Route';

import Layout from './Layout';
import Counter from './Counter';

export default (
<Route path="/" component={Layout}>
    <Route path="/counter" component={Counter} />
</Route>
);
```

**index.js**

```
import AppContainer from 'react-hot-loader/lib/AppContainer';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

const rootEl = document.getElementById('root');

ReactDOM.render(
  <AppContainer>
    <App />
  </AppContainer>,
  rootEl
);

if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept('./App', () => {
    // If you use Webpack 2 in ES modules mode, you can
    // use <App /> here rather than require() a <NextApp />.
    const NextApp = require('./App').default;
    ReactDOM.render(
      <AppContainer>
         <NextApp />
      </AppContainer>,
      rootEl
    );
  });
}
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Router  from 'react-router/lib/Router'
import browserHistory  from 'react-router/lib/browserHistory'
import routes from './routes'

export default () => (
  <Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes} />
);
```

Ошибка возникает при обновлении страницы

> Warning: React attempted to reuse markup in a container but the
>   checksum was invalid. This generally means that you are using server
>   rendering and the markup generated on the server was not what the
>   client was expecting. React injected new markup to compensate which
>   works but you have lost many of the benefits of server rendering.
>   Instead, figure out why the markup being generated is different on the
>   client or server:
>   (client) tid="2">Hello, worldHello, world!

и это

> Warning: [react-router] You cannot change ; it will be
>   ignored

Весь код [тут](https://github.com/perevezencev/react-easy-start)